# Contributing to open research in 2020

Tags: research-process, mathematics, computer-science, independent-researcher

I am interested in getting into a research oriented role in future and would really like to learn more about the process and gain experience by being part of it.

Can someone please share any information about any such current open research initiatives where I can participate or contribute or get a chance to work with other researchers (for example Stanford's crowd research initiative).

Also, if there are other ways, can someone please guide me.

I am particularly interested in the field of Mathematics or Computer Science.

Comment: Computer Science as Open Science could mean participating to projects such as http://refpersys.org/ and contributing to code it on https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/ - feel free to email me to `basile@starynkevitch.net`